# DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)), INTERVAL 1 DAY)

Tags: mysql, google-bigquery

DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)), INTERVAL 1 DAY)- I have this in mySQL, and I'm taking it into BigQuery. BigQuery does not have Last_Day function. 
This getting the first of the month by calculating the last_day of the month before and adding one day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), MONTH), INTERVAL 1 MONTH), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

if you run it today (2019-04-25) the output is

```
Row f0_  
1   2019-02-28
```

Not sure what exactly you your target - I think below  option is better represent your mysql version

```
#standardSQL
SELECT DATE_SUB(DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), MONTH), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

with result

```
Row f0_  
1   2019-03-01
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use    DATE_FORMAT(date ,'%Y-%m-01')

```
   DATE_ADD( DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH) ,'%Y-%m-01'), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```